# Create table from data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript object with this format:

```
{
    "info": {
        "": {
            "apple": "8",
            "orange": "4"
        },
        "Jason Family": {
            "a": {
                "apple": "2",
                "orange": "2"
            },
            "b": {
                "apple": "2"
            }
        },
        "Alex Family": {
            "a": {
                "apple": "2",
                "orange": "2"
            },
            "b": {
                "apple": "2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to parse and display it in table format in Javascript. My expected output as below

```
                Jason Family   Alex family
Apple(8)      |  a(2) |b(2)  | a(2) |b(2) | 
Orange(4)     |  a(2)        |  a(2)      |
```

I am thinking that the best way would be to read the object and create a new one with the structure that I need.I have tried with this:

```
    var str = [];
    str.push('<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="om" id="tbl_data" name="tbl_data" >');
    str.push('<thead>');
    str.push('<tr>');
    str.push('<th  colspan="2" style="vertical-align:middle;">Info</th>');
    str.push('</tr>');
    str.push('<tr>');
    if(data_rtn["info"] != ""){
        str.push('<td colspan="2">');
        for(data in data_rtn){
            if(data == "info"){
                for(midx in data_rtn[data]){
                    str.push('<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="om" style="float:left">');
                    str.push('<tr>');
                    if(midx == ""){
                        str.push('<td colspan="2" style="background:yellow"> &nbsp;</td>');
                    }else{
                        str.push('<td colspan="2" style="background:yellow">'+midx+'</td>');
                    }
                    str.push('</tr>');
                    for(type in data_rtn[data][midx]){
                        for (total in data_rtn[data][midx][type]){
                        if(type == "error"){
                            str.push('<tr>');
                            str.push('<td colspan="2">'+data_rtn[data][midx][type]+'</td>');
                            str.push('</tr>');
                        }else{
                            str.push('<tr>');
                            str.push('<td style="text-align:left;">'+type+'('+data_rtn[data][midx][type][total]+')</td>');
                            str.push('</tr>');
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    str.push('</table>');
                }
            }
        }
        str.push('</td>');
    }else{
        alert("no record!");
    }
    str.push('<tr><td colspan="2"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeDiv();">Close</a></td></tr>');
    str.push('</table>');
    return_data = str.join("");

    $('#pop_list').css({'top':tmpPosy,'left':posx+10,'position':'absolute','text-align':'center'});
    $('#pop_list').html(return_data);
    $('#pop_list').show();
```

The Code above have this output as below

Output:

```
                 Jason Family   Alex family
Apple(8)      |  a(2)        | a(2)       |
Orange(4)     |  a(2)        |  a(2)      |  
              |  b(2)        |  b(2)
```

But the code above do not produce the output as i expected.Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: what does it output? Can you give us possibly a jsfiddle (see jsfiddle.net) or something to let us test it better?

Comment: Use a templating language.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Angular with it. to put the values in the table. See the code below, to get a rough idea. It would save you a lot of code space and also make it faster.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
<td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
.success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
});
</script>
```